# Trying to load shapefile into python

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, import

I am new to both python and QGIS and I am trying to load a shapefile into python and I keep getting an error
when I try to read it.

```
sf=shapefile.Reader('wetland6.shp')
```

---

```
ShapefileException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-dc4b8aeb80b5> in <module>()
----> 1 sf=shapefile.Reader('wetland6.shp')

C:...\shapefile.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    232         if len(args) > 0:
    233             if is_string(args[0]):
--> 234                 self.load(args[0])
    235                 return
    236         if "shp" in kwargs.keys():

C:...shapefile.pyc in load(self, shapefile)
    265                 self.shp = open("%s.shp" % shapeName, "rb")
    266             except IOError:
--> 267                 raise ShapefileException("Unable to open %s.shp" % shapeName)
    268             try:
    269                 self.shx = open("%s.shx" % shapeName, "rb")

ShapefileException: Unable to open wetland6.sh
```

Comment: I'm not a QGIS Python user so I'm only guessing, but could it be expecting to see the full path to the shapefile, eg `sf=shapefile.Reader('C:/data/wetland6.shp')` or similar?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, when you say load shapefile into python do you mean load into QGIS map?

Comment: No, I have generated a model grid in python and I want to superimpose a shapefile over the model grid.  In QGIS I generated a grid of the same dimensions and made a shapefile, but python is unable to open it when I load it into jupyter.

Comment: shapefile isn't QGIS it's shapefile. Can you show the *exact* path you're using to 'load' the shapefile please... your error message says 'can't find or read that file' so it could be one or the other. python uses 'c' style escape chars so a path like c:\Tom is interpreted as c:[TAB]om unless you use the raw string char (r'c:\Tom' is read as 'c:\Tom' but you can't use \n for newline). Can you also check the shapefile *can* be loaded into QGIS and isn't broken.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare where the file is, for example:

```
import shapefile
sf=shapefile.Reader(r'c:/wetland6.shp')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried putting in the full path but got the same problem.  Maybe there is something I have to enable in python, but being a new user I don't know what that is.  I installed pyshp and loaded shapefile.  Is there anything else that needs to be enabled? thanks

Comment: Edit your question with your full path attempt, probably a formatting error